# Django Url and Views cant pass parameters

Tags: python, django, parameters, django-views, parameter-passing

I am using Django 2.1.4 
I Want to Pass a parameter like question_id in the url but i just get 404 .

This is My Code :

**urls.py :**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('index',views.index , name='index'),
    path('index/(?P<question_id>[0-9])',views.detail , name='detail'),
]
```

and this is my :

**view.py**

```
def index(request,):
    return HttpResponse("Welcome To My Page")

def detail(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("new Page" + str(question_id))
```

When I Enter http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/index/12 
in the url , i just get 404 .

Comment: Your regex only matches a single digit; you need `[0-9]+` for more than one. But it's better to use the new path syntax as other answers have pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's the old (prior to 2.0) notation.  I use

```
path('profile/edit_avatar/<int:avatar_id>', views.edit_avatar, name='edit_avatar')
```

in my urls.py  and

```
def edit_avatar(request, avatar_id=0):
```

in my views (with a default value, just in case)

See the Django [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial01/), especially [page 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial03/).

Comment: Thanks This Works For Me .

Answer (score 0):

With Django 2.1.4 the `path` method can parse params in the URL with the following syntax:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('index',views.index , name='index'),
    path('index/<int:question_id>', views.detail , name='detail'),
]
```

If you want to stick to the good old regex, you should probably change your 'detail' view to

```
path('index/(?P<question_id>[0-9]+/$)',views.detail , name='detail')
```

See also [this article](https://consideratecode.com/2018/05/02/django-2-0-url-to-path-cheatsheet/) for more information.